# accessing struct fields inside array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, sdl

I am writing a program which is supposed to build an array of SDL_Rects. Inside a for loop I am assigning values to the fields of SDL_Rect and have a array of pointers point at each rectangle created this way.
This is my code:

```
SDL_Rect *rectangles[n];

for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
{
    SDL_Rect *rect = NULL;
    rect->w = random_int(min_size, max_size);
    rect->h = random_int(min_size, max_size);
    rectangles[i] = rect;
}
```

n, min_size and max_size are all read in from stdin, this is the random_int method:

```
int random_int(int min, int max)
{
    return min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);
}
```

Everytime I try to run my code, I get a "Segmentation Fault: 11" thrown inside the for-loop.
Why is that?

Comment: `SDL_Rect *rect = NULL;
    rect->w = ...` is definitely a glaring problem. `rect` is NULL, so `rect->w` will generate an access violation since you're trying to access an address that is NULL. You need to allocate a pointer to `SDL_Rect` first, such as `rect = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory in `rect` otherwise it is undefined behavior. You were basically dereferencing the `NULL` value which results in UB.

```
SDL_Rect *rect;

rect = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect));
if( rect == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc");
   exit(1);
}

..
..
free(rect);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks :)